# The Masters of Applied Statistics (MAS) is a fairly new degree option. Have they proven to be a good way to start a career as a statistician?

Tags: careers

Most MAS programs are only a few years old, and as such it's hard to find information on career outcomes of program graduates. I'm wondering if anyone who has worked with an MAS graduate, or who has gone through one of these programs could answer a few questions:

1. Is a MAS curriculum by itself sufficient preparation to become a statistician? If you've noticed any deficiencies, what are they?
2. Are there obvious differences in preparedness between an MS in Applied Statistics and a MAS?
3. Is the emphasis on application over theory a serious concern for someone with no intention of going into academia? How much theory is missing?

The MAS programs I've looked into seem closely aligned with my career goals, but I want to know what I'd be getting into with one of these programs.